# PiCamera on VNC display

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vnc

I've recently started working with the Raspberry PiCamera module, and have an issue with image preview. Using `start_preview()` works fine of the Raspberry's physical video output. Now I want to use the Pi through a TightVNC client, so I connect to display 1 as Pi refuses connections to the main display.

When I run my python script remotely through VNC, the camera output is shown on the original Pi display (HDMI output to a separate monitor). **Does anyone have an idea about how to get the PiCamera display on the remote computer?** I've only started using it recently and don't know if I should try to connect to the Pi's main display or change my python script to output the video on the VNC secondary display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your raspberry pi install xRDP for a remote desktop connection

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Use remote desktop connection for windows and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Open the VNC Server dialogue by double clicking the VNC icon on your Pi's taskbar. Open the menu by clicking on the three horizontal lines in the top right corner then go to **Options > Troubleshooting** and select **Enable direct capture mode**.

To close the preview window, you can enter Ctrl-D.

More information is available [on this page](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002249917-VNC-Connect-and-Raspberry-Pi#running-directly-rendered-apps-such-as-minecraft-remotely-0-5).

---

This answer was based on
*[Viewing PICamera V2 via VNC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/69221/137141)* asked at Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange